# Knockout JS Render While Load

Tags: knockout.js, loading, render

If you have a list, and a label for the count.  How can you render each row and increment the label with the new count, in real time as each item gets pushed into the viewmodel array?

For me, the list displayed remains empty, the count is 0, and entire UI is blocked while the viewmodel array gets filled, then when every item is pushed into the array, all the rows in the list just suddenly display along with the final number in the count label.

Comment: Want to show us your code? There is a way to do this, but its going to depend on how you are populating your array.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far that's not working?

Comment: it's hard to abstract my code out... was hoping my description made sense... I've copied over a Knockout sample into a fiddle, tweaked it to load some data.  You can see the UI is blocked and it renders all at once if you click the Add Gifts button.  http://jsfiddle.net/johnmcmillion/YnHQj/

Answer (score 0):

It's very logical that your UI is blocking, as JavaScript is single threaded. Hence, making use of a foreach, will block the rest of the execution of your script.

A quick fix to this would be using setTimeout to delay the execution of the code block. For example if you'd use:

```
for (var i=0;i< totalGifts;i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.gifts.push({name: "New Gift " + i, price: "New Price: " + i});
    },1);            
}
```

Each update will be triggered 1ms delayed and async, hence not blocking your UI. I've updated your fiddle, [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/YnHQj/20/).